# Is there any difference in performance when I use constraints in ASP MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently asked a question about how to create a route that would direct to the same controller with two different paths. Here was the answer suggested to me:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default2",
   url: "{section}/{id}",
   defaults: new { section = "home", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   constraints: new { section = "admin|home" });
```

I also did some more research and came up with this solution:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "spa",
   "{section}/{id}",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
   new { section = @"home|admin" });
```

Does anyone know if there is any performance difference between using one or the other?

Comment: Why do you think there would be performance implications?

Comment: Because one solution lets in every single call and then filters it out  and the other limits what goes in. I also wonder if both will work with Phill Hacks route config or other route config checkers.